# Is it possible to make F1_Score differentiable and use it directly as a Loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, python, optimization, loss-function, f1score

One of the metrics that is widely used in binary classification is the F1 score:

$F_1 = 2\cdot \frac{recall \cdot precision}{recall+precision}$

The problem of the F1-score is that it is not differentiable and so we cannot use it as a loss function to compute gradients and update the weights when training the model. The F1-score needs binary predictions (0/1) to be measured.

I am seeing it a lot. Let's say I am using per example a Linear regression or a gradient boosting.

**Is there any way that it can be minimized directly?**

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.kaggle.com/rejpalcz/best-loss-function-for-f1-score-metric) can help you.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/445055/232706

Comment: @Maeaex1, related: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-unknown-benefits-of-using-a-soft-f1-loss-in-classification-systems-753902c0105d

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is, let's take [$F_1$ score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)  base definition, with : 
$$
F_1 = 2 \times \frac{precision \times recall} {precision + recall} \\
F_1 = \frac{2 \times TP} {2 \times TP + FP + FN}
$$
**And this is the same as the [Sørensen-Dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) coefficient**, also known as Dice coefficient or Bray-Curtis distance. This is a statistical indicator that measures the similarity of two samples :

$$ Dice(X,Y) = \frac{2|X \cap Y|}{|X| + |Y|}$$

Concerning the implementation of this loss, we can approximate $|X \cap Y|$ as the sum of the matrix obtained using [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) ($\odot$, also known as the element-wise product) between the ground truth ($y$) and the prediction ($\hat{y}$). We can then define $L_{Dice}$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
L_{Dice} &= 1 - Dice \\
L_{Dice}\left(y, \hat{y}\right) &= 1 - 
        \frac{ 2\sum y \odot \hat{y}}
             {\sum y + \sum \hat{y}} 
\end{align*}

You will often find this loss in the context of [segmentation problems](https://towardsdatascience.com/metrics-to-evaluate-your-semantic-segmentation-model-6bcb99639aa2), as well as others quite close, such as the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) (IoU).

Comment: Isn't $\sum y \odot \hat{y}$ the same as the dot product of $y$ and $\hat{y}$, since both are one-dimensional vectors?

Comment: I like it. What are the gradient and hessian? We take derivative w.r.t. $\hat{y}$, right?

Comment: I'm trying to implement this as an objective for XGBClassifier. https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

Comment: If I consider each $y_i$, $\hat{y_i}$ to be independent, then my loss becomes $L_i = 1 - \frac{2 y_i \hat{y_i}}{y_i + \hat{y_i}}$. If I use a sigmoid for $\hat{y_i}$ to let the model predict a logit, which we squash to a probability, then $L_i = 1 - \frac{2 y_i \sigma(\hat{y_i})}{y_i + \sigma(\hat{y_i})}$. Then first and second derivative w.r.t. $\hat{y_i}$ can be found: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+%281+-+%282y+s%28x%29%29%2F%28y+%2B+s%28x%29%29%29, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+%28-2y%5E2+s%28x%29%281-s%28x%29%29%29%2F%28%28s%28x%29%2By%29%5E2%29

Comment: I get better results using the cross entropy loss, though: $L(y,\hat{y}) = -\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i} y_i log(\sigma(\hat{y_i})) + (1-y_i) log (1-\sigma(\hat{y_i}))$, where
$\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$ -> $L_i = - (y_i log(\sigma(\hat{y_i})) - (1-y_i) log(1-\sigma(\hat{y_i})))$ -> $\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y_i}} L_i = -y_i + \sigma(\hat{y_i}) $ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \hat{y_i}^2} L_i = \sigma(\hat{y_i})(1 - \sigma(\hat{y_i}))$

Answer (score 2):

Following on Thomas, on the relation between the Bray-Curtis distance and the F1 score and the calculation of the first and second-order derivatives: If one defines the Bray Curtis distance between vector X and Vector Y as: $\sum |X_i-Y_i| \over {\sum (X_i+Y_i)}$, than the first derivative to $x$ is $d \over (dx)$ $|x - y| \over {(x + y)}$ = $2y(x - y) \over{\big((x + y)^2(|x - y|)\big)}$ and the second derivative is ${d^2 \over{dx^2}} {|x - y| \over(x + y)} = {-4y*(x - y) \over\big((x + y)^3*(|x - y|)\big)}$

Comment: How can I use this? As $x$, or as I might call it $\hat{y}$ approaches $y$, the gradient and hessian explode, because the denominator goes to 0. Seems like the optimum must be an unstable one.